# laravel ajax 500 internal server error

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

after changing my AJAX from GET method to POST method,
I got this internal server error 500 every time the JavaScript runs.
And I really cant find anything wrong.

Im using laravel 4.2 on windows.

JavaScript function on keyup:

```
function usernameCheck()
{
var input = document.getElementById("usernameInput");
var icon = document.getElementById("userIcon");
var xmlhttp,
    username = document.getElementById("usernameInput"),
    message = document.getElementById("usernameMessage");

if(username.value != "")
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            message.innerText = "";
            icon.style.color = xmlhttp.responseText;
            input.style.border = xmlhttp.responseText+" solid 2px";

            if(username.value.length < 4)
            {
                message.innerText = "username is too short";
                message.style.color = "red";
            }
            else if(xmlhttp.responseText == "false")
            {
                message.innerText = "username is already in use";
                message.style.color = "red";
            }
            else if(xmlhttp.responseText == "true")
            {
                message.innerText = "username is available";
                message.style.color = "green";
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "usernamevalidation", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-    urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("username="+ username.value);
}
else
{
    icon.style.color = "";
    input.style.border = "";
    message.innerText = "";
}
}
```

Route.php:

```
Route::post('usernamevalidation', 'UserController@validateUsername');
```

Comment: Use firebug or other dev tools to debug. Post detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reaction, i'm having FBL.ns.XMLHttpRequestWrapper.send error with FireBug.

Comment: @LaurensSmid Are you sure this is the error your server is returning? Look in the response object for the specific ajax request. 500 is a server error, the problem is in your server side code not your javascript.

Comment: I found the problem, it's was about the php function that wasn't able to run.

Comment: sorry which php function... i have this same error... trying to figure out the problem

Comment: It was just a problem in the function i was linking to,

Comment: it doesnt matter wich one, if the php doesnt run the javascript wont load.

Comment: Have you tried using `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in you form and pass through your data